# ionic + cordova + crosswalk = error 401 on file transfer download

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-runtime

I added crosswalk to my android project and cordova file transfer download operation, which was working prior to adding crosswalk, stopped working. I get http error 401. I checked from different browsers and the server is serving the file just fine without any authorization issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

## Details

We had an issue of crashing of app while using `FileTransfer` & `Crosswalk` it turned out it was an issue of `FileTransfer` was trying to access `cookie` and didn't succeed to do it.

## Work around

Apply this code https://github.com/gaochun/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/commit/0063249e279b99a0feb4601650fc3a4c9e8a8ed2?diff=split

note that the diff is not from the latest version of `FileTransfer` but it can be easily apply on `cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.1.0 "File Transfer"`